# jQuery Tooltip widget well-suited to use with an IMAGE-MAP? suggestions/recommendations please

Tags: jquery, tooltip, imagemap, jquery-tooltip

I would like to display different tooltip content for each of the areas defined in an image-map. Are there any jQuery plug-ins that have an API well-suited to use with image-maps? I would like it also be be flexible with regard to where the tooltip content comes from, e.g. the content might be contained in an anchor element of an invisible iframe or it might come from a database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already found something, I'd recommend [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) (although the map areas in the example aren't matched up to the image that well).

Answer (score 7):

I've just started using JQuery-UI's tooltip:

```
$("area").tooltip({ track: true });
```

Simple.